# Select more than one element in one statement in R xmlGetAttr?

Tags: r

I can write  `xmlGetAttr(x,"title")` and `xmlGetAttr(x,"href")`to get the atttributions "title" and "href",
can i compound two statement into one?
`xmlGetAttr(x,c("title","href"))` can not work.
Error in a[[name]] : attempt to select more than one element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xmlAttrs`

```
xmlAttrs(x)[c("title","href")]
```

as an example:

```
require(XML)
udata<-htmlParse('http://cran.r-project.org/')
frames<-getNodeSet(udata,'//*/frame')
# > xmlAttrs(frames[[1]])[c('src','name')]
#         src        name 
# "logo.html"      "logo"
```

Answer (score 0):

The paths in `getNodeSet` or `xpathApply` can be character vectors with more than one element

```
attrs <- c("src", "name")
paths <- sprintf("//frame/@%s", attrs)
```

so with @user1609452 's helpful reproducible example

```
require(XML)
udata<-htmlParse('http://cran.r-project.org/')
vals <- xpathSApply(udata, paths)
```

and then for instance

```
matrix(vals, ncol=length(attrs), byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(NULL, attrs))
```

leading to

```
> matrix(vals, ncol=length(attrs), byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(NULL, attrs))
     src            name      
[1,] "logo.html"    "logo"    
[2,] "navbar.html"  "contents"
[3,] "banner.shtml" "banner"
```